# Divide a field by a field in the previous row with awk

Tags: csv, awk

I try to do an operation on a field in a csv row involving a field from the previous row, then add the result as a new field in the csv. But I can't find the correct way achieve that.

Example input data:

```
2020-03-05,21
2020-03-06,58
2020-03-07,107
2020-03-08,162
```

Outout data:

```
2020-03-05,21,0
2020-03-06,58,2.76
2020-03-07,107,1.84
2020-03-08,162,1.51
```

What I tried already:

```
awk -F, '{ if ( NR > 2 ) { result = $2/"field_$2_from_previous_row"; print $0","result; }}'
```

I'd like to find a way to match a field in the previous row. (I know that the next step will be to avoid division by zero, of course).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show what the expected result looks like for the input data shown?

Comment: I just edited the question to add the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","; OFMT="%.2f" }
{
    print $0, (prev ? $2 / prev : 0)
    prev = $2
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
2020-03-05,21,0
2020-03-06,58,2.76
2020-03-07,107,1.84
2020-03-08,162,1.51
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
awk -F, '{
    if (NR>1) result=$2/field2
    print $0","result
    field2=$2
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple ways (not the only way) is simply to store the value of the 2nd field in `n`, and if it is set, output the additional field that is the result of `$2/n`, if it isn't set, output the record unchanged appending `0`, e.g.

```
awk -F, 'n{printf "%s,%.2f\n",$0,$2/n;n=$2;next} {print $0","0; n=$2}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data in `file`:

```
$ awk -F, 'n{printf "%s,%.2f\n",$0,$2/n;n=$2;next} {print $0","0; n=$2}' file
2020-03-05,21,0
2020-03-06,58,2.76
2020-03-07,107,1.84
2020-03-08,162,1.51
```

An alternative shorter version using a ternary (twice) to control the output:

```
awk -F, '{printf n?"%s,%.2f\n":"%s,%d\n",$0,n?$2/n:0;n=$2}' file
```

Whichever makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

data.txt your data,
script s.awk about the content:

```
// {
if (NR == 1) {
  r=0
}
else {
  r=sprintf("%.2f", $2/tmp)
}
print($0","r)
tmp=$2
}
```

Execution:

```
awk -F, -f s.awk data.txt
```

Result:

```
2020-03-05,21,0
2020-03-06,58,2.76
2020-03-07,107,1.84
2020-03-08,162,1.51
```